# Como usar um método que está dentro de uma classe e soma dois números no Ruby

Tags: ruby, método

```
class Soma

def somar(num1, num2)

    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
    result = num1 + num2

    puts "O resultado é #{result}"
end
```

end

somando = soma.new (1, 2)

Não consigo entender por quê o seguinte código não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que criar uma instância da classe e depois chamar o método desejado. Assim:

```
class Soma
    def somar(num1, num2)
        @num1 = num1
        @num2 = num2
        result = num1 + num2
        puts "O resultado é #{result}"
    end
end

somando = Soma.new()
somando.somar(1, 2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SMteM7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zkpqbglp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/CallMethodInObject.rb).

Só note que isto não faz sentido. Não deveria criar uma classe para isto, deveria fazer de forma muito mais simples e de forma mais correta separando o cálculo da impressão, assim:

```
def somar(num1, num2)
    return num1 + num2
end
 
puts "O resultado é #{somar(1, 2)}"
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://repl.it/join/xtzuibyy-maniero). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zkpqbglp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/CallSimpleMethod.rb).

Comment: Tentei fazer desta forma pra fixar melhor o uso de classes, pretendia criar mais classes para outros tipos de contas mais complexas como o resultado de fórmulas, só uma pergunta, os parênteses depois do "Soma.new" é necessário? Obrigado, ficou bem mais claro essa questão de instanciar classes!

Comment: Melhor não fixar isto, porque está aprendendo errado. Primeiro aprenda o básico para depois ir para o mais complexo. A primeira coisa que deve aprender sobre classes é que só deve criá-las se tiver um motivo muito bom para isto. Na verdade tudo em programação. Quanto menos código melhor, cada coisa que acrescentar precisa de boa justificativa. Os parenteses não são obrigatórios em Ruby, mas gosto de usar pra deixar claro que é um método e não outra coisa.

Comment: @Iseeyouthere agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.